# Storing fetched value in a session

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm unable to store the value in my session variable.
The fetching from query is done alright as it displays the correct value.
`Response.Write(Session("idsess"))` Won't return anything.
This is my code:
IS IT A SYNTAX THING?

```
con.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT ([password]) FROM userinfo WHERE ([uname]= '" & uname_log.Value & "')", con)

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If (dr.Read) Then
            If (dr(0).ToString = pass_log.Value) Then

                cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [profile_id] FROM userinfo WHERE ([uname]= '" & uname_log.Value & "')", con)
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
                dr.Read()
                Response.Write(dr(0).ToString)

                If (dr.Read) Then
                    Session("idsess") = dr.Read()
                    Response.Write(Session("idsess"))
                End If

            Else
                Response.Write("Wrong Authentification.")
            End If
        Else
            Response.Write("Sign up instead?")
        End If

        con.Close()
```

Comment: Is this a web form, windows form or console app? If it was a syntax thing I would expect you get an error... if you do what is it?

Comment: There are no errors and its a web form. AM I STORING IT CORRECTLY HERE- `Session("idsess") = dr.Read()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `DataReader` correctly; change your code in:

```
If dr.Read Then
    Session("idsess") = dr("profile_id")
    Response.Write(Session("idsess"))
End If
```